# Laravel elixir not found when running gulp in cli

Tags: node.js, laravel, gulp, laravel-5

It has been pretty frustrating finding the solution to this problem today, as I've tried searching on Google and went to all of different forums and websites in search of a solution, but none of them worked for me.

Is there anyone who could tell me what I could try in order to solve this?
Facts:

1. Fresh Laravel installation
2. Ran `npm install`
3. Ran `npm install gulp`
4. Ran `gulp`
5. Got this error

[image]

**package.json contents**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the `node_modules` directory completely and issue `npm install` or `npm install --no-bin-links` without gulp, gulp should already included in packages.json

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Have done all of that already before asking this question :) Same error still

Comment: then please provide the content in your packages.json file

Answer (score 0):

Very old question I know, but, if still having issue...
Try to run

```
npm install laravel-elixir --save-dev
```

command manually on prompt.

And then make sure you added following code line in gulpfile.js file

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
```